# how to achieve zoom-in/zoom-out in AndroidView/UiKitView in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I need a zoom-in/zoom-out camera integrated using `AndroidView` (for the Android Side) and `UiKitView` (for the iOS Side).
I have mentioned my code below

```dart
     Platform.isAndroid
                  ? AndroidView(
                      viewType: 'camera',
                      layoutDirection: TextDirection.ltr,
                      creationParams: creationParams,
                      creationParamsCodec: StandardMessageCodec(),
                      gestureRecognizers: <Factory<OneSequenceGestureRecognizer>>{
                        Factory<OneSequenceGestureRecognizer>(
                          () => EagerGestureRecognizer(),
                        ),
                      },
                    )
                  : UiKitView(
                      viewType: 'camera',
                      layoutDirection: TextDirection.ltr,
                      creationParams: creationParams,
                      creationParamsCodec: StandardMessageCodec(),
                    ),
```

I have tried a lot but did not get success in this.

If you have any idea how to do this please let me know.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
import io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel;

private static final String CAMERA_CHANNEL = "camera_channel"; 

MethodChannel cameraChannel = new MethodChannel(getFlutterView(), CAMERA_CHANNEL);
cameraChannel.setMethodCallHandler(
        (call, result) -> {
            if (call.method.equals("setZoom")) {
                double zoomLevel = call.argument("zoomLevel");
                result.success(null); // Return success
            } else {
                result.notImplemented();
            }
        }
);
```

then

```
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

void setZoom(double zoomLevel) async {
    try {
        await _channel.invokeMethod('setZoom', {'zoomLevel': zoomLevel});
    } catch (e) {
        print('Error setting zoom: $e');
    }
}
```

now you can call setZoom